# How to write conditioned loop in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

How can I write this Java code in kotlin?

In Java:

```
int test = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5-test; i++){
        test+=1;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Output of java: 0,1,2

My Try in Kotlin:

```
var test = 0
for (i in 0..5 - test) {
    test += 1
    println(i)
}
```

Output of kotlin: 0,1,2,3,4,5

The output should be: 0,1,2 (as I'm changing test variable inside)

But I want the "for loop" to decrease based on the "test" variable.

**UPDATE found a solution**

```
var test = 0
for (i in 0..5) {
    if(i>5-test) break;


    test += 1
    println(i)
}
```

Output: 0,1,2 (As I expected)

Comment: `0..5 - test` creates a [`Range`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) which the loop then iterates over. So `test` is only being evaluated once at the beginning, when creating the range. You can't do it with this syntax in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution, Post Updated :)

Comment: Sure, but why not just write `if (i > 2) break;`?

Comment: Actually, I will change the "test" variable inside the loop based on some conditions which will decrease the number of iteration. There is no certainty that the loop will run for 2 or 3 times. Let me share my problem and solution. I want to duplicate zeros in array of integers [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0] to [1,0,0,2,3,0,0,4]. Solution: [LINK](https://pl.kotl.in/NRm_eHC9T) . Here notice in first for loop in duplicateZeros function.

Answer (score 0):

Have read the documentation : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/loops.html

`for (x in 10 downTo 0)`

Comment: Thank you, but notice I want "test" variable to affect in loop condition which I will change inside the loop.